# Communication between OBD device (STN1110) and android over Wi-Fi

Tags: java, android, android-wifi, obd-ii

Hi I am  developing an android application , in which there is a communication part between an OBD device and android device , I am planning to use the **STN1110/OBD II** protocols for communication over Wi-Fi network. I have checked in Google but it was not quite satisfied for me.I am looking for some good articles for this can anybody suggest some useful links or working examples? ... have a good day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15117475/android-elm327-obd2-protocol/15684739#15684739

Comment: Here is nice article about developing OBDII Reader application for Android using Bluetooth adapter:
http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/how-guide-obdii-reader-app-development
You can easy adapt provided sample to work with a WiFi.

Comment: I have already seen that , but I need the communication over wi fi ..and above that the parsing of incoming data using OBD II protocol.